# How to make this AppBar shape in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create the AppBar as shown below:
[image]

I have tried to change the shape of AppBar but there is a visible separation between body and AppBar, as shown below:
[image]

I have come up with a solution by putting the body in stack and placing a separate widget for the curved area of AppBar and positioning it below the AppBar to make it look like it's a part of AppBar. I want to know if there is another way to achieve this?
current solution using Stack looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You can provide the code that you used to achieve the app bar shown in the second screenshot.

Comment: This will work i have checked  appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(25),
          ),
        ),
      ),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the pink color comes from the widget in the `body`, and not the `Scaffold` background color. If that's the case, you can set `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true` in the `Scaffold`:

```dart
Scaffold(
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  // ...
)
```

While the creation of rounded app bar itself is done by providing `RoundedRectangleBorder` as its shape:

```dart
AppBar(
  // ...
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(20)),
  ),
)
```